# Customers are not able to register on frontend

Tags: customer

Some time ago i posted kinda the same question, but this one is better detailed and contains the actual problem.

I got messages that customers are not able to register an account on the frontend, Im using hellowired theme, on their website i saw a fix for the problem by inserting a code, however this did not work, in of the comments on the topic someone said i should use the base login.phtml and this did not work as well.

I believe the problem is really in the login.phtml, although i can't find out where or what it is.

Anyone who can help me out here maybe? Googled the problem and only got variations of it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your magento version ?

Comment: Magento version 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There You may not have form_key

Try to insert `<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />` code on login page within `<form></from>`

Comment: Sorry, reacted too soon... I have inserted the form_key, i got from the hellowired website. After i did that, customers still couldn't register unfortunately.

Comment: What is the url of your website??

Comment: ittd.nl/magento

Comment: You have error on your site. so i m not able to see

Comment: I got the error fixed, you can visit website again now, it's ittd.nl/magento

Comment: As i see that your login is working fine. So you need to add this code on account create form..  Go to app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml. And add `<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />`  after line 44   Let me know the result.

Comment: Hi! log in is working fine yes, register is not, i did the above as you and it did not work, customers who try to register still get nothing if they press the button, the page simply just refreshes unfortunately

Comment: As i can see that you still not added this code you made some mistake . Paste my code after `<input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />`. And then clear your cache

Comment: Alright, i did it, and refreshed the cache, however, it still doesn't work unfortunately? If you neef the form to look into if i made an error perhaps, just let me know, i will paste it here,

Comment: Yes please paste it

Comment: Alrighty,  here it is (the code is too long to just paste it so heres the pastebin link             http://pastebin.com/Yqzmk32V

Comment: http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints  Follow this steps and enable template path hints to see that this is right file we are editing

Comment: Let me know the results

Comment: I enabled path hints, thanks to the tutorial you send me, what's next?

Comment: Go to `frontend/base/default/template/clarion/customerattribute/form/register.phtml` and do the same which you did some time ago for register.phtml

Comment: Let me know if this solved

Comment: It worked!!!!  Thank you so much! i was stressed out and afraid to lose more clients, but now it's up and running again! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

May be it's  `form-key` issue follow this step:

1. Go to `app/design/frontend/[Your-package]/[Your-theme]/template/customer/form/login.phtml` and template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml and under
2. Find: `<ul class=”form-list”>`
3. And paste this right after the code above the following:

   `<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo`     `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />`

Repeat above for `app/design/frontend/Your-package]/[Your-theme]/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`

Also may be there will be issue in Cookie path and cookie domain

Path should be `/`

domain should be `yourdomain.com`

- `Mage.Cookies.path     = '/';`
- `Mage.Cookies.domain   = '.yourdomain.com';`

This  setting are manage from admin.
`Admin>System>configuration>General>Web>Session Cookie Management`

Comment: Gonna write it down so i won't forget,  go to the paths you suggested,  and paste   input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />        above the <ul class=”form-list”>         or paste    <ul class=”form-list”> above the <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" /> ??

Comment: Is its work for you ?

Comment: I'm gonna try it, but should i paste the <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />     above    the <ul class=”form-list”> or  the <ul above the form key?

Comment: yes, please do it and let me know

Comment: I did it, and unfortunately it did not work,    would it be helpful if i paste my login.phtml here so you can see if it has errors, or if i perhaps have input the wrong code?

Comment: plz enable path hints and check right file location for login.phtml in that file you need to add if form_key is missing

Comment: i do not know how to enable path hints, but the the login.phtml is in the right location, i checked it a second ago